# Free Barcode Scanning Alternatives for Xamarin Android Development

Tags: android, xamarin, components, barcode

I'm searching a free alternative for scanning barcodes in Xamarin.Android Development. Actual we have problems with zxing because it doesn't start the scan Function and now I need a new free alternative for the component.

Hope somebody can help.

Greeds

Answer (score 0):

I found ZBar a good alternative. I have used it and it is quite easy to integrate. Try it out. If you case any problem, let me know.

Comment: Is this realy working for Xamarin.Android Projects? Because I only find instructions for the Xamarin iOS SDK

Comment: Don't get it how to bind the zbar.jar in a Xamarin Android Project

Comment: You need to create a binding library using the jar file.